# Script error with Highcharts with histogram

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to implement a histogram with Highcharts. The histogram is not displaying as I get notified of a script error, but I don't see what is wrong with the code.

```
var data = [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3,
    4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4,
    3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5,
    3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9,
    2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9,
    3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6,
    3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9,
    2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7,
    3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1,
    3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Histogram'
    },

    xAxis: [{
       
        title: { text: 'Histogram' },
        alignTicks: false,
        opposite: false
    }],

    yAxis: [{
        title: { text: 'Histogram' },
        opposite: false
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        histogram: {
            accessibility: {
                point: {
                    valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.x:.3f} to {point.x2:.3f}, {point.y}.'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Histogram',
        type: 'histogram',
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        baseSeries: 's1',
        zIndex: -1
    }]
});
```

The code won't display.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load `histogram-bellcurve` module and correctly configure your series and axes.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/histogram-bellcurve.js"></script>
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0qLcahn4/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/histogram-series